# jQuery change function

Tags: jquery, onchange

In jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/dbcottam/d8VLJ/) I have finally succeeded in getting my code to work properly... when a LOB is selected, it brings up the subLobs.  However, when I impliment it into my working code, it doesn't work.

The code below is how it is implemented in my jsp, the fiddle provides this and the html that goes with it.

I have tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE - none work, any ideas why it doesn't? Do I need this in an `OnLoad`?

```
<script>
$('#txtLob').change(function () {
if ($('#txtLob').val() == "United Traditional") {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
    $('#lineOfBusiness').append("<select name='txtSubLob' id='txtSubLob'><option value='None'>None</option><option value='United CAPSIL'>United CAPSIL</option><option value='United LMF'>United LMF</option><option value='United Vantage'>United Vantage</option><option value='United DI Rider'>United DI Rider</option></select>");
} else if ($('#txtLob').val() == "Universal Life") {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
    $('#lineOfBusiness').append("<select name='txtSubLob' id='txtSubLob'><option value='None'>None</option><option value='CAPSIL'>CAPSIL</option><option value='Vantage'>Vantage</option><option value='TAG'>TAG</option><option value='VUL'>VUL</option></select>");
} else if ($('#txtLob').val() == "Companion Traditional") {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
    $('#lineOfBusiness').append("<select name='txtSubLob' id='txtSubLob'><option value='None'>None</option><option value='Companion CAPSIL'>Companion CAPSIL</option><option value='Companion LMF'>Companion LMF</option></select>");
} else if ($('#txtLob').val() == "Health Reinsurance Ceded") {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
    $('#lineOfBusiness').append("<select name='txtSubLob' id='txtSubLob'><option value='None'>None</option><option value='NHALR_DLR'>NHALR_DLR</option><option value='CI Ceded'>CI Ceded</option><option value='Western and Southern'>Western and Southern</option></select>");
} else if ($('#txtLob').val() == "Med Supp Assumed") {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
    $('#lineOfBusiness').append("<select name='txtSubLob' id='txtSubLob'><option value='None'>None</option><option value='Internal ADM MS Assmd'>Internal ADM MS Assmd</option><option value='External ADM MS Assmd'>External ADM MS Assmd</option></select>");
} else {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
}
}).trigger('change');   
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure you load your code at the end of the page before the closing body tag or in the head via a document ready call. jsFiddle automatically wraps your code in an onload call.

Comment: You probably need a DOM ready handler. Open your console (F12) and check for errors.

Comment: Did you include jQuery?  (And as @adeneo suggested, your code should be in a ready handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your code in a `$(document).ready(function(){});`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#txtLob').change(function () {
  if ($('#txtLob').val() == "United Traditional") {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
    $('#lineOfBusiness').append("<select name='txtSubLob' id='txtSubLob'><option value='None'>None</option><option value='United CAPSIL'>United CAPSIL</option><option value='United LMF'>United LMF</option><option value='United Vantage'>United Vantage</option><option value='United DI Rider'>United DI Rider</option></select>");
  } else if ($('#txtLob').val() == "Universal Life") {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
    $('#lineOfBusiness').append("<select name='txtSubLob' id='txtSubLob'><option value='None'>None</option><option value='CAPSIL'>CAPSIL</option><option value='Vantage'>Vantage</option><option value='TAG'>TAG</option><option value='VUL'>VUL</option></select>");
  } else if ($('#txtLob').val() == "Companion Traditional") {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
    $('#lineOfBusiness').append("<select name='txtSubLob' id='txtSubLob'><option value='None'>None</option><option value='Companion CAPSIL'>Companion CAPSIL</option><option value='Companion LMF'>Companion LMF</option></select>");
  } else if ($('#txtLob').val() == "Health Reinsurance Ceded") {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
    $('#lineOfBusiness').append("<select name='txtSubLob' id='txtSubLob'><option value='None'>None</option><option value='NHALR_DLR'>NHALR_DLR</option><option value='CI Ceded'>CI Ceded</option><option value='Western and Southern'>Western and Southern</option></select>");
  } else if ($('#txtLob').val() == "Med Supp Assumed") {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
    $('#lineOfBusiness').append("<select name='txtSubLob' id='txtSubLob'><option value='None'>None</option><option value='Internal ADM MS Assmd'>Internal ADM MS Assmd</option><option value='External ADM MS Assmd'>External ADM MS Assmd</option></select>");
  } else {
    $('#txtSubLob').remove();
  }
  }).trigger('change');   
});
</script>
```

Fiddler does this for you, so that's why it works there but not on your page.

Comment: duh! Thank you! For some reason I thought that because it was a .ready(function) that I didn't need it in the $(document).ready  Thanks!